# Python Error - Not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, sql, django

Hi I have the following query to Database. It is working correctly in SQL, but not working in python. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT distinct id , id FROM XX WHERE id LIKE '01%' GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the `%` to escape it, as Django treats it as a format string where `%` characters have special meaning:

```sql
SELECT distinct id, id FROM XX WHERE id LIKE '01%%' GROUP BY id
--                                              ^^
```

Comment: But am getting a strange error as 
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'XX'`

Comment: @blackwindow: How are you using the query in Django? Please add your actual code to your question. Give us the *full* traceback for the error too.